# Qlikview screenshot extension

Tags: qlikview

I'm using screenshot extension to make png files from dashboards.

It's working properly but in one page I'm using geoqlik. Bbut when I get screenshot from this page this extension  is not shown in png files.

Comment: GeoQlik? QlikView? What system and environment? Extension reference?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: What extension object are you using for screenshots? It may be the case that it doesn't support the display of non-standard objects like GeoQlik.